# Facebook user and friends user display patterns for Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: facebook, metro, windows-8

I'm developing a win 8 metro app (html) with facebook integration. At windows 8, i cannot use the facebook social plugin to show user informations...

So i need to construct my HTML and css to show the user picture and name...

Where can i find models or patterns to do:

- A box to logged out users
- A box to logged in user
- A box with some user friends that plays the game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official UX guidelines for Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424.aspx#tiles_and_notifications) has a section about tile and notifications with a link to a page that has [even more specific guidelines for tiles and notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx).

There is a wide range of desired visual styles with examples like the below, that show how, concretely, things should be done.

[image]

In your question the actual design problem you face seems a bit vague, but I am sure those two links provide you with pleanty of examples and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can check IBNLIVE website's http://ibnlive.in.com/ or http://ibnlive.in.com/movies/ right side. They also have a vertical box of various sections.

Comment: This site uses the social plugin... Im looking for a customized examples... But, thanks for your answer :D

Comment: Ok. Intention was to share a UI pattern to show different category of user. Did you find it useful? Assuming this info will be show before game starts, you will have plenty of space to use. Also, are you looking for a design for tablets or normal PC?

Comment: Im developing for Windows 8 (PC/Tablet). Im looking for something simple, like the start win 8 page [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nvvM5.png). I just looking for patterns like, the size of the name, the box, the picture, bordes, magins, padding, etc...